# How do I get a count of values by month in linq to sql?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-group

I have a table of feedback scores, which essentially contains a date field and a "score" field (which may be "happy", "neutral" or "sad").

I want to return a query which gives me the count of each score by month, like this:

[image]

However, my query isn't grouping correctly - I'm basically getting three rows for each month (one row for "happy", one for "neutral" and one for "sad", like this:

[image]

How do I aggregate the data together?

My query at the moment is this:

```
var monthlyScore = from f in db.tl_feedbacks
    group f by new { month = f.timestamp.Month, year = f.timestamp.Year, score = f.tl_feedback_score.score } into g
     select new
            {
              dt = string.Format("{0}/{1}", g.Key.month, g.Key.year),
              happyCount = g.Where(x => x.tl_feedback_score.score == "happy").Count(),
              neutralCount = g.Where(x => x.tl_feedback_score.score == "neutral").Count(),
              sadCount = g.Where(x => x.tl_feedback_score.score == "sad").Count(),
              total = g.Count()

          };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `, score = f.tl_feedback_score.score` from your grouping.

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks - can't believe it was so obvious!